# Wordpress heading <tag> Forbidden 403 Error (clean install)

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I keep getting a Forbidden 403 error from [mydomain/wp-admin/post.php](http://mydomain/wp-admin/post.php). 
The error only occurs when text is wrapped in a **heading tag** such as `<h1>`, error appears upon pressing save draft, publish or update.

As soon as the heading tags are removed, I am able to successfully save draft, publish or update.

Has anyone come across this issue, is this something specific to my installation or a bug?

Details:

- Wordpress version  4.7.5
- Fresh install through cPanel
- post.php file permission 644

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was mod_security that was somehow triggered. 
I contacted hosting provider and they resolved the issue. I'm guessing this occasionally happens with new site deployment.